# Linear Regression to predict a simple formula result using Weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, linear-regression, weka

I have a simple train data as follow. The result is calculated by formula (**price * 100**).

### Train Data

Price, Result

1, 100

15, 1500

2.3, 230

5.23, 523

3.245, 324.5

100, 1000

### Test Data

Price, Result

4.567, 456.7 (this result 456.7 to be predicted by formula price * 100)

Is there a way to do it by Weka?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your datasets, turning them into valid CSV format:

**Train**

```
Price,Result
1,100
15,1500
2.3,230
5.23,523
3.245,324.5
100,10000
```

**NB:** The last line also required 10,000, not 1000 as Result value to comply with your rule of `Result = Price * 100`.

**Test**

```
Price,Result
4.567,456.7
```

**Build model**

You can build a model, either using `weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression` or `weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLinearRegression` from the terminal like this (and output the generated rule):

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLinearRegression -t train.csv -T test.csv
```

**NB:** You will need to adjust paths to the `weka.jar` and your train/test CSV files.

**Predictions**

If you want to output predictions for the test set, then you can use something like this:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLinearRegression -t train.csv -T test.csv -classifications weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.PlainText
```

**NB:** You will need to adjust paths to the `weka.jar` and your train/test CSV files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is really helpful. I wish I could upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Would really appreciate if you could suggest this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378613/text-classification-with-weka-java-api